# Pam.exec exit code 8

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, pam

I'm trying to use `pam.d` to execute a script on user login. Right now I'm editing the `/etc/pam.d/su` file. Every time I log in to a user I get "Exit code 8".

The command I use:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /etc/calendar/test
```

The path `/etc/calendar/test` is the path to the test script:

```
echo hi
```

Eventually I will implement a script that logs the user that logged in and what time:

```
user=$(whoami)
date=$(date)
echo $user logged in at $date >> /etc/calendar/tripwire_file
```

Any insight provided on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will never see any output unless you add the `stdout` option. By default `pam_exec` sends all output to `/dev/null`. See [pam_exec](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html)

Comment: How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: There is a good example at the end of the link I provided. Whether you "should" is more the question. `pam_exec` dates back to 2006 and has a number of caveats on the UID is runs under you need to check into. From the look of it simply adding `stdout` before `/etc/calendar/test` should allow the `echo hi` to run, but are you sure `sh` is the correct policy name to invoke it?

Comment: Well the whole point of this is to have a program run when a user logs in. If there is a better way to do this I would love to know.

Comment: I'm not being coy. If I knew a simple solution, I'd provide the answer, but looking there is no default policy for `sh` and I'm not sure whether `sh` would invoked on login or whether that is simply causing an error in pam stack. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will be able to add more info.

Comment: I'm also meant to type "su" instead of sh. I will edit the post

Comment: I tried adding stdout to the line making it:

Comment: Ok, that at least makes more sense as `su` is a standard policy, but I'm not sure that is run unless someone invokes it by attempting to become the SuperUser.

Comment: session optional pam_exec.so stdout /etc/calendar/test
This did not work. Im still getting exit error 8

Comment: Why not try adding it to `login` instead of `su`?

Comment: I still get the exit code 8 if I move it to login.

Comment: I'm out of ammo. I've never played with that. You may want to try migrating the post to [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). While it does involve scripting, it's more "How do I setup `pam_exec`?". See if you get more help here, and if not, consider the other sites.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Same issue here, any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem, adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of my script file fixed it.